# Python-Boto errors - eonfiguring SaltStack for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, salt-stack

I have attempted to test a bunch of custom SaltStack grains & modules utilizing python boto modules for AWS deployments, but have continuously run into Python errors.

Generally, I was unable to import modules correctly when running, because Salt is defaulting to Python 2.6. Even though my install has both Python 2.6 & 2.7, the Salt master & minion default to 2.6. Generally the modules I've tested so far run manually fine under 2.7.

How can I configure the Salt master and minions to default to Python 2.7?

I've seen this in various peoples `salt --versions-report` for unrelated issues, but I can't figure out how to achieve it myself on CentOS/RHEL.

Seems even if I have an OS with a base of Python 2.7, as soon as `salt-master` is installed via yum, there comes Python 2.6. I've tested on CentOS 6.x & Amazon Linux (which should be similar), which are the main OS'es I use.

How do I enforce Python 2.7? Is it not possible with CentOS/RHEL/Amazon, would I need another distro?

Comment: Did you setup the correct repo for your salt .  Please cleanup the current salt repo in your OS and refer to this setup  http://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel

Comment: Not sure if it was being stuck on Salt 15.5.2 or general install issues with python. It was an older installation from a time when Salt was basically broken on AmazonLinux, and I'd employed a bunch of workarounds.. Fresh install from latest/correct repo did the trick though, custom modules no longer crying over python, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps I should push as best practice to saltstack documentation about the repo issues  ;-)